# how to apply a style by printing svg from javascript

Tags: javascript, css, svg, printing

by printing svg from javascript I got my chart without styles.css. Any ideas how to add styles?

```
function print(){
    var element = document.getElementById("chart");
    var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    var view = serializer.serializeToString(element);
    console.log(view);
var printWin = window.open('','','left=0;top=0;width=800;height=600;toolbar=0;scrollbars=0; status=0;');
    printWin.document.write(view);
    printWin.document.close();
    printWin.print();
    printWin.close();
```

}

if want to know what I mean check this screenshot http://de.tinypic.com/r/30auvec/5
I need somehow to point on my styles.css file which is located not in the same file

Comment: Have you tried just dong `view = '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/styles.css"/>' + view;`?